# Filter 10k over Object is lagging

Tags: javascript, typescript

An Api returns over 10k Objects in the form of `{firstName:'john',lastName:'Cena'}`. In my parent React component, I am making the API call on the component that did mount and passing this object to Child Components.

In the Child Component when the user key in, it is lagging. I tried using the `callback` method but issue persist.

Parent Component

```
const Filters = ({validation}: any) => {
    
    const [EmployeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState<any[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        //get and set
    },[])

    return (
        <>
             <Staff EmployeeList={EmployeeList}/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Child Components

```
 
const onChange = useCallback(
        (e: any) => {
            const userInput = e.currentTarget.value
            if(staffList){
                setFilteredSuggestions(staffList.filter(
                    staff =>
                        staff.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1 
                ))
            }
            setUserInput(e.currentTarget.value)
        },
        [userInput]
    )
```

Comment: You should use an indexing map, but maybe also limit the number of suggestions and/or requiring a minimal of user input length. Another solution would be to append a few suggestions at a time in a callback (setInterval), and allow user input in the meantime, cancelling the obsolete requests.

Comment: Yes I am planning to limit the number of suggestions to 20. But again you have provided with so many options. May I know which one is the best solution.

Comment: The best is the simplest that fulfills your requirements. If limiting to 20 already solves your lag, that's the best solution! Try and see.

Comment: @Wyrzutek I am wondering how to limit the objects to 20. . can you provide any samples. thanks

Comment: I have put it as answer, because the code formatting would not be readable here in the comments.

Comment: May I know if I still need to use ```useCallback```??

Comment: Yes, you still need useCallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a `for` loop instead of `filter` (you could use `filter` and return false for all elements after the first 20 positives, but it would not be efficient).

Instead of

```
setFilteredSuggestions(staffList.filter(
        staff => staff.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1 || staff.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) > -1
    ))
```

you can do

```
const input = userInput.toLowerCase() // moved this out to do toLowerCase() only 1 time instead of 20k
const filtered = []
for (const staff of staffList) {
    if (staff.firstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1 || staff.lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
        filtered.push(staff)
        if (filtered.length >= 20) {
            break
        }
    }
}
setFilteredSuggestions(filtered)
```

Comment: its pretty fast now. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.